# Mount discs manually

Tags: centos, mount

In the past I clicked in the graphical file manager on the symbols for the attached disc. The window appeared which asked me for superuser password and the disc was mounted automatically.

But now I am working on a headless VM and can't access the graphical file manager anymore.

I know that I can list the discs with `lsblk` and mount them with `mount /dev/sdX /mountpoint`.

What confuses me, is that the "graphical automount" mounted the disc to `/run/media/<username>/<discname>`.

My question is if `mount /dev/sdX /run/media/<username>/<discname>` is identical to the above described "graphical automount".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if `mount /dev/sdX /run/media/<username>/<discname>` is identical to the above described "graphical automount".

Yes, it usually is. However, that graphical automount is often done or accessible from the given `<username>`. But quite often, the mounts are done from root during boot time (see [fstab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)).

I guess you would want to edit `/etc/fstab` for a mount on some toplevel directory (e.g. `/extrahome/` or `/home2/` etc...)

Read also [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).